# TypeError: object is not a function, when it is!

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am having trouble with some Ajax functionality.

I have a single dropdown that needs to update a record when the option changes. Here is a snippet of the Javascript:

```
function changeResponsibleParty(selectObj, targetDiv){
    var idx = selectObj.selectedIndex;
    var which = selectObj.options[idx].value;
    target = document.getElementById(targetDiv);
    target.value = which;
    document.forms["changeResponsibleParty"].submit();
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<form name="changeResponsibleParty" action="javascript:changeResponsiblePartyAjax('project_todos');" method="post" style="display:inline;">

<input type="hidden" name="todo_id" id="todo_id_15" value="15" />
<input type="hidden" name="project_id" id="project_id_15" value="2" />
<input type="hidden" name="user_id" id="user_id_15" value="" />

<select name="user_id_pick" id="user_id_pick_15" onchange="changeResponsibleParty(this, 'user_id_15');" style="border:0;">

<option value="0">Anyone</option>
<option value="1" selected="selected">Allen McCabe</option>
<option value="2">Thomas Martinez</option>
</select>
</form>
```

I am using the function to update a hidden input element because for some reason, the  tag was posting 1 regardless of which option I chose (1 is my user_id, which I set as selected if the database record value is 1.

Can anyone see what is wrong here?

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using something like jQuery? It will make this process much easier.

Comment: Figure out why you're having trouble with the HTML rather than writing a JavaScript kludge that is entirely unnecessary and requires JS enabled to work... no, he doesn't need jQuery or any JavaScript at all to submit a straight form with no logic!

Comment: Does the error give a line number and if so what is the code on that line?

Comment: `action="javascript:changeResponsiblePartyAjax` that's not the name of your function, nor should you be specifying a JavaScript function as the action attribute of the form.

Comment: @Dan I didn't read the entire question. I saw that he was using legacy event-handling and so that was a knee-jerk comment. I do notice the mistake that you're talking about.

Comment: Dan Grossman first comment is right, rather fix the bug then work around it with the possibility of more bugs.

Comment: @Vivin Paliath I am starting to incorporate more jQuery into my projects; I was initially just trying to get this to work so I could move on. Thanks.

Comment: @Dan Grossman I things to function this way for Ajax, I have removed PHP and other unnecessary code for the purpose of this question.
Also, why is it bad to use a JavaScript function as the action? This is imperative to the functionality of many elements in this project. Thanks.

Comment: You should bind an event handler to the submit event of the form to have JS code run when the form is submitted.

Comment: @DanGrossman I am not submitting this form; it should update a database record as soon as it is changed. This saves the page from having to load.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You use **changeResponsibleParty** as name for the form and also as name for the function, which will cause conflicts. Rename one of them.

Comment: I find it almost impossible to believe that it works. The form has no real URL for that "submit()" to work!  How is the browser supposed to figure out what to do when you call "submit()"?

Comment: @Pointy browsers are amazing things aren't they.

Comment: This may work. Assume that the function changeResponsiblePartyAjax() has no returnValue --> `return void(0);` . So what happens: the function will do what it has to do(I guess it will send an ajax-request ) ...and that's all.

Comment: @Stack 101 I did! I just had to wait because the website made me :)

Comment: @Dr.Molle Changing the option will call the ajax function which looks into the hidden form element and updates a database record with it. So the user is presented with a select box with employee names. Changing a name will update the database without having to click a submit button.